# Is there a measure for connectedness?

Tags: graphs, terminology

Is there a name for the "measure of connectedness", i.e. :
$$\text{MoC} = \frac{d(G)}{|G|-1}$$ with domain of function $D_\text{MoC} = [0,1]$, average degree of graph $d(G)$ and amount of nodes $|G|$? Meaning a quantitive measure for connectedness or meshedness of a graph? E.g. a complete graph would have a MoC of 1, while a graph without edges would have a MoC of 0.

Comment: There are other possible ways of measuring sparseness, but often the most appropriate one depends on your application. Quite central to algorithmic graph theory are various width measures, like treewidth and cliquewidth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your measure is known as the [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_graph) of the graph, and is given by the formula $$ \frac{|E|}{\binom{|V|}{2}}, $$
where the graph is $G = (V,E)$.

Comment: Can you please explain the notation of the |V| on top of  the 2?

Comment: It's a binomial coefficient (q.v.).